Can I ask questions like these?
Can I ask for examples of words/sentences satisfying a set of requirements?

By words/sentences I truly mean just a sequence of 1 or more words that can be part of a bigger structure.
And by requirements I really mean anything, from the role this chunk of text would play in the context where it is put, to the whether it can be used in that context only or also in other contentexts and so on.

For instance, is it legit to ask questions like these? (By the way none of the 3 following example are questions I'd ask. The ones I've in mind are bit longer as they'd require more explanation, so I just made up these examples.)

Is there in Italian a word for a concrete concept that can be used in two distinct figurative ways? Take pozzo. It is a Scavo […] a sezione per lo più circolare […] nel terreno […], but it can be used in locutions like "un pozzo di scienza" where it means "somebody with a lot of". But can it be used, still figuratively, to mean something else? (I have no idea what the answer would be.)
Is there a two letter word which carries a meaning and is not just a grammatical element? (The answer would be yes, there is, and one example is tè.)
Does Italian have a construction corresponding to English's saxon genitive? (As far as I know the answer is a plain no.)


Without going into much detail, the main question I'd like to ask is whether in Italian there's an instance of a word which can be used in a concrete way, in a figurative way, with the concrete having another way of being written which doesn't work if used in a concrete way.

As long as the question explains what exactly you do not understand, or what you have found before asking the question, the questions should be acceptable. I understand that some questions are asked because the person asking them speaks a different language where a specific construct would be correct, but a question like Does Italian have a tense for future events, or does it use a construct like English does? would probably be not much helpful to future readers.

The second example is not clear, to me. tè is a noun. I am not sure I would not call it a grammatical element, if that means part of speech. Also, every word carries a meaning; eventually, there are words that can be omitted, but that does not mean they do not have a meaning.
